# JSTL nested forEach on Array showing up empty

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, foreach

I've got a adminpanel.jsp page that is supposed to show all the names of the users and each of their arrays. I've got a nested forEach loop. The top-level loop works fine, it displays the information as requested.

The second loop comes up as an empty array. `[]` 
I've checked within my program, the array itself IS populated.

This is my .jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    UserService us = ServiceProvider.getUserService();
    List<User> allUsers = us.getAllUsers();
    request.setAttribute("allUsers", allUsers);
%>
    <h1>This is the admin panel</h1>

<c:forEach step="1" var="user" items="${allUsers}">
    <h3>${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</h3>
    <c:out value="${user.allPomodoros}" /> // shows up empty
    <c:forEach step="1" var="pomodoro" items="${user.allPomodoros}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
                <th>Pomodoro ID</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>${pomodoro.userID}</td>
                <td>${pomodoro.beginTime}</td>
                <td>${pomodoro.endTime}</td>
                <td>${pomodoro.isCompleted}</td>
                <td>${pomodoro.pomodoroID}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

If you need any additional information, let me know.

Comment: If ${user.allPomodoros} doesn't print anything, then the getAllPomodoros() method returns null or an empty collection. There's nothing in the posted code that could lead us to think otherwise: no code of User, nothing printed showing that the collection isn't empty, etc. Also, remove step="1": it's useless noise.

Comment: verify your data in the bean with System.out.println(...);
then check server logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user.firstName shows up. Debug your program, add a break point after < request.setAttribute("allUsers", allUsers);>. add custom variable allUsers.get(0) to check what you really get for allPomodoros.

Comment: You are right, something is not right in my program. Trying to figure out what.

Thanks for pointing it out.